# Late 90s/early 2000s anime movie where a research facility in a snowy place is attacked by Americans

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime

This anime movie was released late 90s up until 2004.

All I remember of the movie is that the scientists are at a research facility in a snowy and ice covered place, when a band of Americans shows up and starts killing everyone and one of the mercenaries uses a minigun.

Comment: Can you recall any other details? This might not be much to go on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are referring to the anime [*Spriggan*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spriggan_(manga)#Film) (1998).

From [MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/anime/420/Spriggan):

> Deep in the Ararat Mountains of Turkey, a secret organization known as ARCAM has found what is believed to be Noah's Ark. However, the U.S. Machine Corps., a rogue organization of the Pentagon, wants to take over the Ark as a means of global supremacy. Only a special ARCAM operative known as a Spriggan stands in their way. Japanese Spriggan Yu Ominae teams up with French Spriggan Jean-Jacques Mondo to combat members of the U.S. Machine Corps. led by Col. MacDougall—a genetically-enhanced boy with deadly psionic powers. However, they must act fast and stop MacDougall before he uses the Ark for his own agenda.

Below is the ice fight scene.

Comment: Can you provide any details to indicate that this is the correct one?

Comment: @ Adamant - I've added in a Youtube clip showing the ice fight scene detailed in TheOtakuGamer's question - unfortunately I can not find any text indicating that information.